# How to check only month and year in MySQL DateTime column in Vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im saving some calculated values in to database each month.Before saving, i want to check data is already available for this month and year. IF the same month exists, then user has to select another month or leaving without saving that. In Vb.net, im using DateTimepicker for selecting month and save that in DateTIme format in mysql. In that i want to check only month and year is existing.

Mysql:

```
1   2019-05-01 14:24:20   ProA       8.34   3.59
2   2019-05-01 14:24:20   ProB       9.21   5.54
```

Here record available for ProA for May2019 is available. So user cannot save for may 2019 again.

```
    Dim selectedDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim startDate = New Date(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1)

    conn.Open()
    sQuery = "SELECT * FROM riskanalysis WHERE DATE_FORMAT(reportdate,'%c %Y') >= @StartDate "
    cmd_listview = New MySqlCommand(sQuery, conn)

    cmd_listview.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate)       

    Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd_listview.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            ' User already exists
            MsgBox("Record Already Exist for this Month!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Select another month!")
        Else
            sQuery = "INSERT INTO riskanalysis (reportdate, process, avgrisk, avgriskafterImp) VALUES (@dat, @process, @avgrisk, @riskafterimp);"

            For i As Integer = 0 To ProcessRiskGridView.Rows.Count - 1

                cmd_listview = New MySqlCommand(sQuery, conn)

                cmd_listview.Parameters.AddWithValue("dat", DateTimePicker1.Value)
                cmd_listview.Parameters.AddWithValue("process", ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
                cmd_listview.Parameters.AddWithValue("avgrisk", ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                cmd_listview.Parameters.AddWithValue("riskafterimp", ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                cmd_listview.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next               
    End Using
    conn.Close()
```

I tried for some mysql command but it didnt work.

Comment: Why not take it as it is and then substring it in vb.net to get month and year part? That way you can check the results you're getting so you can compare them later

Comment: What bit isn't working? Is there any error? or is the query simply not firing etc.

Comment: IF i pass directly DateTimePicker value,then it always returns false..i dont know how to seperate month and year from Datetimepicker as well as in DateTime format and compare this two.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Select * to find out if a record exists. Just get the count. Don't retrieve data you don't need. You certainly don't need a reader.

Keep your database objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using blocks will handle this for you even if there is an error.

Don't use .AddWithValue See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

You keep adding parameters to the collection over and over on each iteration. They only need to be added once. The value of @dat remains the same for all iterations. Only the values of the last 3 parameters change. You seem to be mixing up column names and parameter names. We are dealing with parameter names.

I have guessed at datatypes. Check your database for the actual datatypes and be sure to convert the values from the grid cells to the proper type if necessary. I don't know what kind of grid you are using and if it returns proper datatypes for .Value.

Example:
`cmd.Parameters("@avgrisk") = CDbl(ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)`

```
Private Sub MySql()
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Dim selectedDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim startDate = New Date(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1)
    Dim sQuery = "SELECT Count(*) FROM riskanalysis WHERE DateTimeColumnName >= @StartDate; "
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sQuery, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate
            conn.Open()
            retVal = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    If retVal <> 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Record Already Exist for this Month!")
        Return
    End If
    sQuery = "INSERT INTO riskanalysis (reportdate, process, avgrisk, avgriskafterImp) VALUES (@dat, @process, @avgrisk, @riskafterimp);"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sQuery, cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@dat", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = selectedDate
                .Add("@process", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@avgrisk", MySqlDbType.Double)
                .Add("@riskafterimp", MySqlDbType.Double)
            End With
            cn.Open()
            For i As Integer = 0 To ProcessRiskGridView.Rows.Count - 1
                cmd.Parameters("@process").Value = ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                cmd.Parameters("@avgrisk") = ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                cmd.Parameters("@riskafterimp") = ProcessRiskGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```